# Why splitted flow is not invoked in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have following job configuration:

```
@Bean
public Job job(Step databaseToDataBaseLowercaseSlaveStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(csvToDbLowercaseStep())
            .next(databaseToDataBaseLowercaseSlaveStep)
            .split(jobTaskExecutor())
            .add(new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow2")
                    .start(notificationStep())
                    .build()
            )
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

**Expected ordering of actions**:

1. Execution of `csvToDbLowercaseStep`
2. Run in parallel 2 steps 
   a)`databaseToDataBaseLowercaseSlaveStep`
   b) `notificationStep`

**Actual ordering of actions**:

1. Execution of `csvToDbLowercaseStep`
2. Execution of `databaseToDataBaseLowercaseSlaveStep`

So `notificationStep` was not invoked at all. Why? How can I correct it ?

### Update

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    // there are 21 sites currently hence we have 21 threads
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25);
    taskExecutor.setThreadGroupName("cust-job-exec-");
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("cust-job-exec-");
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a split to a chain of states is not supported, this is the correct way to do what you want (task 1 synchronous followed by tasks 2 and 3 in parallel):

```
    public Job job() {

        final Flow masterFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow1").start(step("step1")).build();

        final Flow slaveFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow2").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .add(
                        new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow2.1").start(step("step2.1")).build(),
                        new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow2.2").start(step("step2.2")).build())
                .build();

        return (jobBuilderFactory
                .get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(masterFlow)
                .next(slaveFlow)
                .build())
                        .build();
    }

    private TaskletStep step(final String name) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get(name)
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {

                    System.out.println(name + " start");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println(name + " end");

                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
```

step1 start

step1 end

step2.1 start

step2.2 start

step2.1 end

step2.2 end

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Your code is trying to add a split to a chain of states, and as per the doc for FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder it is simply not supported.

```
     * <em>Note:</em> Adding a split to a chain of states is not supported.  For example, the following configuration
     * is not supported.  Instead, the configuration would need to create a flow3 that was the split flow and assemble
     * them separately.
     *
     * <pre>
     * // instead of this
     * Flow complexFlow = new FlowBuilder&lt;SimpleFlow&gt;("ComplexParallelFlow")
     *                       .start(flow1)
     *                       .next(flow2)
     *                       .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
     *                       .add(flow3, flow4)
     *                       .build();
     *
     * // do this
     * Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder&lt;SimpleFlow&gt;("parallelFlow")
     *                       .start(flow3)
     *                       .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
     *                       .add(flow4).build();
     *
     * Flow complexFlow = new FlowBuilder&lt;SimpleFlow&gt;("ComplexParallelFlow")
     *                       .start(flow1)
     *                       .next(flow2)
     *                       .next(splitFlow)
     *                       .build();
     * </pre>
```

Comment: You covered a half of the question - how to run steps in parallel. Another part what is going on with my code.

Comment: added executor configuration

Comment: I dug further in and found that the pattern is simply not supported as per the doc. Updated my answer.

Comment: How to print the count of total task in the above example? @Captain